# Sumif in Excel with macro only adding a range of numbers based on their date

Tags: vba, excel

Excel 2013 with a macro. The macro will mirror whatever number from range("C2:C") and put data in corresponding textbox in the UserForm.  The file will automatically change the date in cmbDate.

I want only to mirror only those numbers that we're added on that same date.

My current setup is that It will add everything even if they have different dates.

Here's screenshot: [image: Screenshot]

code:

```
Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()

Dim x As Integer

With Sheet1
    With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        .Offset(1).Resize(1, 3).Value = Array(txtDate.Value, cmbNetwork.Value, txtCharge.Value)

        End With

        'txtDate.Value = ""
        cmbNetwork.Value = ""
        txtCharge.Value = ""

End With

Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim lastrow As Long

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    'If Cells(i, "A").Value = CDate(cmbDate.Value) Then
        If Cells(i, 2) = "ATT" Then
        a = Cells(i, 3) + a

        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = "Verizon" Then
        b = Cells(i, 3) + b

        ElseIf Cells(i, 2) = "Comcast" Then
        c = Cells(i, 3) + c
        End If
    'End If

Next i

'Range("A16") = a

txtAtt.Value = a
txtVerizon.Value = b
txtComcast.Value = c

x = CDbl(txtAtt.Value) + CDbl(txtVerizon.Value) + CDbl(txtComcast.Value)

txtTotal.Value = x

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2") = txtAtt.Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F3") = txtVerizon.Value
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F4") = txtComcast.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: *"My current setup is that It will add everything even if they have different dates"*: that's normal because you commented out the checking of the date. What happens if you uncomment it?

Comment: Lol that fix the issue..Thanks.The cmdDate can be change value. Is there a way for it to use it as a filter in searching previous data. For example let's say current date is July 30, and I will try to view data for July 28, I can simply select July 28 and will see all it's data.

Comment: Yes sure there's a way, but that would be a different question. For instance you can select another date in the combo and click the button again, simply. If what you need is something different, feel free to ask another question and make your requirement as clear as possible.